# How to properly post data using begin/end GetRequestStream and callbacks

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I'm trying to post a piece of data but it seems to be getting caught and hangs (but not throwing an error).

```
 internal IAsyncResult RequestGet<TPostType>(Action<string> callback, string path, TPostType value)
    {
        var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Connection.GetUri(path).Uri);
        http.Accept = "application/json";
        http.ContentType = "application/json";
        http.Method = "POST";

        var parsedContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(parsedContent);

        return http.BeginGetRequestStream(ar => 
        {
            try
            {
                var stream = http.EndGetRequestStream(ar);
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                stream.Close();

                http.BeginGetResponse(body =>
                {         
// its around here that it hangs.
                    var response = http.EndGetResponse(ar);

                    var s = response.GetResponseStream();

                    ReadStream(callback, s);

                }, null);
            }
            catch (WebException webex)
            {
                WebResponse errResp = webex.Response;

                using (Stream respStream = errResp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(respStream).ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }, null);
    }
```

There were a few times when it didn't hang but told me that the request body was missing, however I didn't make any progress beyond that. Could someone please inform me as to what I'm doing wrong?

The ReadStream method works for GET requests, but for context:

```
private static IAsyncResult ReadStream(Action<string> callback, Stream stream)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[5000];

        var asyncResult = stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, 5000, ar2 =>
        {
            try
            {
                callback(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, 5000));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // do better error handling
                Console.WriteLine("exception reading stream");
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }, null);

        return asyncResult;
    }
```

For more context on how its being used:

```
 public IAsyncResult BeginGetChainPart(Action<BlockData.BlockList> callback, int height)
    {
        var asyncResult = new HttpConnector(Connection).RequestGet(body =>
        {
            callback(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BlockData.BlockList>(body));
        }, "/local/chain/blocks-after", new BlockData.BlockHeight { Height = height });

        return asyncResult;          
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you've chosen APM instead of TAP asynchrony? My opinion is that the reduced cognitive load of TAP/`async`/`await` vs. the distributed nature of logic when using APM callbacks pretty much makes APM yesterday's news.

Comment: yes. It needs to be compatible with Mono/Unity. i will later "wrap" it with .NET4.0 code and make both wrapped and unwrapped versions available. but the inner workings need to be .NET2.0, hence APM

Answer (score 0):

found the solution, posting in case anyone comes across the same issue:

```
        internal IAsyncResult RequestGet<TPostType>(Action<string> callback, string path, TPostType value)
    {
        var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Connection.GetUri(path).Uri);
        http.Accept = "application/json";
        http.ContentType = "application/json";
        http.Method = "POST";

        var parsedContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(parsedContent);

        return http.BeginGetRequestStream(ar => {
            try
            {
                var stream = http.EndGetRequestStream(ar);  

                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                stream.Close();

                var response = http.GetResponse();

                var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                ReadStream(callback, responseStream);

            }
            catch (WebException webex)
            {
                WebResponse errResp = webex.Response;

                using (Stream respStream = errResp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream);

                    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
        }, null);
    }
```